# Firestore Set Data in a document as separate fields

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I am get the multiple fields from my document in firestore and then I use the data to set the same `fields` from the doc into another doc. There are a lot of fields in one document. How can I do this without writing each field name?

```
db.collection('sourceCollection').doc('sourceDoc').get().then( snap => {

    const data = snap.data()
    //from what I see this is an array now with fields in it

        db.collection('newCollection').doc('newDoc').set({
        //What do I put here so I can set the content of data as separate field in the newDoc 

        //if I do the following I get an array field called `data` within the new doc which is not what I want; I need the content of the `data` to be SEPARATE fields in the newDoc

         data

        //I also dont want to write each field because there are too many so the following wouldn't work for me: 
        fieldName: data.sourceDocFieldValue,
         ...
         })
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just pass `data` without putting it in curly braces.

```
db.collection('newCollection').doc('newDoc').set(data);
```